# Postfix not working on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, email, postfix

I've followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-22-04 and configured postfix on Ubuntu 22.04. But, when I try to test with the following command:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" myemail@yahoo.com
```

I get errors on /var/log/mail.log:

```
Oct 12 04:32:42 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/anvil[88609]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:133.144.233.206) at Oct 12 04:29:22
Oct 12 04:32:42 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/anvil[88609]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:133.144.233.206) at Oct 12 04:29:22
Oct 12 04:32:42 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/anvil[88609]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct 12 04:29:22
Oct 12 04:33:53 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/pickup[87341]: 39EFF17C363: uid=1000 from=<ubuntu@mydomain.com>
Oct 12 04:33:53 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/cleanup[88723]: 39EFF17C363: message-id=<20221012043353.39EFF17C363@ip-172-31-2-101.ap-west-2.compute.internal>
Oct 12 04:33:53 ip-172-31-2-101 postfix/qmgr[87340]: 39EFF17C363: from=<ubuntu@mydomain.com>, size=435, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Can you give suggestions how I can fix this kind of errors? Thank you.

Comment: Amazon has done a lot of stuff to block EC2 instances from sending or receiving email via postfix. You will need to get in touch with AWS customer service in order to work out how your instance(s) will use postfix, how many messages will be sent, to who, and so on. Many years ago, Amazon was blocked by all mail providers for all the spam and, as a result, they are *very* careful about how messages are sent. Be aware that AWS Customer Service will point you to their own email sending service.

Comment: yes, I think this is the issue. Already, I've contacted with their customer service. Hope that it can work if throttled restriction is modified.